# How to generate a high or low?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]I have a logic gate that needs a high(1) or a low(0) to one of the inputs going into the logic gate. In the picture on input A going to the nor gate you can see that one of the inputs says 0, and on input F the nand input says 1. How do I generate this?

Comment: Is the picture relevant? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, sorry in the picture on input A going to the nor gate you can see that one of the inputs says 0, and on input F the nand input says 1. This relates to my question because I don't know how you would generate the 1 or 0?

Comment: If you're talking about a physical circuit, you generate a `1` by connecting the input to Vcc and a `0` by connecting to ground. Depending on the circumstances, you may want to insert a resistor instead of a direct connection.

Comment: Okay, that is exactly what I needed to know. Wasn't sure if I needed resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect those signals to Ground (0) or Vdd (1).

The purpose of those gates in the circuit is to act like an inverter. You could replace both of those gates (the NAND and the NOR) with an inverter each and it would act the same. The fact that you have inverters in the schematic makes me question why they're not inverters.

If this block is going to be black-boxed and used in a bigger piece, I'm surprised those lines aren't connected to input lines. In that way, you could have them act as inverters in one block and normal gates in another usage of the black-box.